# Purpose of hemisphere under shuttle nose cone (Enterprise)

Tags: space-shuttle, engineering, aerodynamics, shuttle-enterprise

I noticed a small hemisphere protruding from the dorsal side of the Enterprise space shuttle's nose cone, forward of the front landing gear. I have no clue what its purpose is but am far from an expert in aerospace engineering. Does anyone here know what it's for?

[image]
<sup>[Image Source: Space Race Leadership](https://spaceraceleadership.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/space-history-can-you-name-the-1st-space-shuttle/)</sup>

Comment: Interesting. Neither this feature nor the large circular plate near the top are on the space-worthy Orbiters.  The large circular plate near the top appears to be where the air data probe was attached for the drop tests.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: There are also a bunch of ovals cut out of the tiles. Not sure why they're there either. Maybe it's a similar purpose? (visible in the source image from above)

Comment: WAG: Radar altimeter?

Comment: A navigation light?

Comment: @aml It looked pretty opaque, but I can't say for certain. Lighting wasn't the best.

Comment: I looked up the radar altimeter on the space-worthy orbiters.  That system used 4 C-band antennas on the lower forward fuselage.  Enterprise might have had something different though.  http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/sts-gnnc.html#sts-gnnc-altimeter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's an easy one....   S Band Antenna.....

[image]

This image comes from the document [JSC-13864 SPACE SHUTTLE ORBITER
APPROACH AND LANDING TEST FINAL EVALUATION REPORT](http://www.klabs.org/DEI/References/general/alt_final_report.pdf).  It is on page 134 of the pdf.

Here is a close up picture of the antenna, from [here](http://www.space1.com/Artifacts/Space_Shuttle_Artifacts/Other_Parts/S-band_Antenna/s-band_antenna.html)...

[image]

Comment: `-1` You should add a link to a verifiable source for these images. You should also give credit to the source of images you use here.

Comment: THe Enterprise drawing is not online and belongs to a private individual who is now deceased.   I have permission to use it from the family.   The S-band photo is online at the following. Site                                                                                                             .http://www.space1.com/Artifacts/Space_Shuttle_Artifacts/Other_Parts/S-band_Antenna/s-band_antenna.html

Comment: I'm truly sorry to hear that. Do you think it is possible to find a similar drawing somewhere? Possibly someone else here will be able to help also. In general it's important to try to show sources for data and credit images. I think personal collections make an occasional appearance, but it's an exception rather than the rule. I've added your link back into the answer, and with that edit I can switch my vote back to `+1`. It's a great answer!

Comment: Over the past 10 years I have been in touch with and become close friends with many of the Challenger 8, those 8 individuals that were labeled by the Rogers Commission as the "Idiots who launched in the cold"    They are not and never were idiots and they have shared a great deal of information and data with me that was not in the "Official" report.    I am not sure what the managers source for that Enterprise drawing was, but I can look at the original document and see if there is any indication of its author.

Comment: @ChallengerTruth I edited your answer to provide an online reference for your drawing (a link to the document it came from).  Feel free to revert the edit if you don't approve.

Comment: I received a large number of documents from an MTI manager and a copy of that line drawing was included.   But this looks like his source for that picture.   Thank you.